# Get the largest data number from jQuery elements

Tags: jquery

I have a list of divs each with data id numbers.

```
<div id="divblocks">
<div data-id="200"></div>
<div data-id="210"></div>
<div data-id="170"></div>
<div data-id="230"></div>
</div>
```

How can I get the largest id number out of this succession of DIVs?

Something like this:

```
maxid = jQuery('#divblocks').find("div").max().data("id");
```

Comment: In the simplest form this would require a loop and some comparisons, so... What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the divs and compare the ids in pairs:

```js
var highest_id = 0;
var id;
$('#divblocks > div').each(function(i,e){
    id = $(e).data('id');
    if(highest_id < id){
        highest_id = id;
    }
});

alert(highest_id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divblocks">
    <div data-id="200"></div>
    <div data-id="210"></div>
    <div data-id="170"></div>
    <div data-id="230"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My long version:

```js
const $divs = $('#divblocks div')

// parsing nodeList to arrayList
const arrayDivs = Array.from($divs)

// getting array ids values
const arrayDataIds = arrayDivs.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc.push($(item).data('id'))
  return acc
}, [])

// getting max value of ids
const largestId = Math.max.apply(null, arrayDataIds)

console.log(largestId)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divblocks">
    <div data-id="200"></div>
    <div data-id="210"></div>
    <div data-id="170"></div>
    <div data-id="230"></div>
</div>
```

small version:

```js
const $divs = $('#divblocks div')

const largestId = Math.max.apply(null, Array.from($divs).reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc.push($(item).data('id'))
  return acc
}, []))

console.log(largestId)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divblocks">
    <div data-id="200"></div>
    <div data-id="210"></div>
    <div data-id="170"></div>
    <div data-id="230"></div>
</div>
```

to target div:

```
$(`div [data-id="${largestId}"]`)
```

Comment: _"parsing nodeList..."_ jQuery doesn't return a "node list". It's a array-like collection of elements/nodes.

Comment: There's no need for `Array.from()` and `Array.prototype.reduce()`. Just use jQuery's `.map()`